# What is the meaining of ?p in WordPress URLs?

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

In my 404 log, I find a lot of accesses to the following URL pattern:

```
/blogs/page/1361/?p=hdwvshhe
```

What does that mean and what is the usage of the p parameter?

Answer (score -1):

all ?p=hdwvshhe means is someone is trying to access some WordPress content with the ID of hdwvshhe. This would suggest that content doesn't exist anymore/never existed. the ?p= is just the parameter to say 'Content ID' essentially.

Depending on the frequency of that error it could be malicious or it could just be accidental bookmarking of old content etc